# Flask + jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, flask

Yet another question about flask and jquery autocomplete. I have been reading and trying the following answered questions without any success:

[Flask AJAX Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310644/flask-ajax-autocomplete)

[Using jQuery autocomplete with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365821/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-flask)

In particular the second answer is perfectly matching my case.

However for some reasons (maybe it's me not understanding what is supposed to do), the callback `autocomplete(..)` is executed only once when I load the page (and correctly autocomplete the value in `NAMES`) but never while typing in the textbox.

**search.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

{{ form.autocomp.label }}: {{ form.autocomp }}

<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**application.py**

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

import wtforms as wt
from wtforms import TextField, Form

NAMES=["abc","abcd","abcde","abcdef"]

class SearchForm(Form):
    autocomp= TextField('autocomp',id='autocomplete')

@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('term')

    app.logger.debug(search)
    return Response(json.dumps(NAMES), mimetype='application/json')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    return render_template("search.html",form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
from flask import jsonify

NAMES=["abc","abcd","abcde","abcdef"]

@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('term')

    app.logger.debug(search)
    return jsonify(json_list=NAMES)
```

In Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: data.json_list,
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The search field is always None.. How to pass the value in the textbox to python?

Comment: Hi @kartheek, I am trying to implement autocomplete feature but its not working for me. Could you please help me.

Due to word limitations, I have put my code in pastebin at 
http://pastebin.com/fY2AXm3X

Comment: This didn't work for me as well (search is always None). I tried [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712822/1194761) and that worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because a missprint in a suggested piece of code:

```
from flask import jsonify
NAMES=["abc","abcd","abcde","abcdef"]
@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('term')
```

Change in *search = request.args.get('term')* 'term' to 'autocomplete'. So correct code should be as follow:

```
from flask import jsonify
NAMES=["abc","abcd","abcde","abcdef"]
@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('autocomplete')
```

Comment: Pradeepb, it works for me too. Sorry for my mistake because I missunderstood request.args.get('term') parametr.