# jQuery autocomplete in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, autocomplete

Can't make jQuery autocomplete widget work with Flask framework. (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote here is an example)

In **manage.py** I got the following :

```
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    results = []
    search = request.args.get('autocomplete')
    for mv in db_session.query(Movie.title).filter(Movie.title.like('%' + str(search) + '%')).all():
        results.append(mv[0])
    return jsonify(json_list=results)
```

My **index.html** file:

```
    <head>
    ...
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                    source: data.json_list,
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
       <div>
          <input name="autocomplete" type="text" id="autocomplete" class="form-control input-lg"/>
       </div>
    ...
    </body>
```

Looks like dev tools in firefox don't return any errors.
The terminal returns the following:

> "GET /autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
> "GET
>   /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 
> "GET /static/js/jquery.js
>   HTTP/1.1" 304 -

The widget just doesn't work. Since I don't know much about jQuery I can't figure out what causes the problem. Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Is your ajax works and reaches to server side?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Below is working JS/jQuery and Flask code:

```
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('q')
    query = db_session.query(Movie.title).filter(Movie.title.like('%' + str(search) + '%'))
    results = [mv[0] for mv in query.all()]
    return jsonify(matching_results=results)
```

HTML/jQuery:

```
<head>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{
                q: request.term, // in flask, "q" will be the argument to look for using request.args
            }, function(data) {
                response(data.matching_results); // matching_results from jsonify
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.value); // not in your question, but might help later
        }
    });
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input name="autocomplete" type="text" id="autocomplete" class="form-control input-lg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

A bit of explanation is in order: 'q' is your search term argument name as defined in jQuery's $.getJSON ajax call. That's passed to flask, and picked up using `request.args.get`. The database query is constructed from that, and a list comprehension is used to construct the results. Note that with list comprehensions you don't initialize the list, nor do you use a for+append combination; one elegant line does everything.

Next, jsonify returns the list `results` wrapped as a dictionary with the key `matching_results` holding the results list. Do not be tempted to use `json.dumps` to return a list to your ajax call. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435297/how-do-i-jsonify-a-list-in-flask) why (TL/DR: security concerns).

Note also that i've deliberately changed some variable names so you could tell what script/flask function 'sees' which variable. E.g., the ajax call doesn't see the list `results`, it sees `matching_results`. And that's inside (now javascript's) `data` object.

To grab the list `matching_results` is the key for, use the pattern in the attached script. It's messier than simply sending a list, but more secure, and eventually will allow you to do more sophisticated things on the client-side using JS/jquery.

Finally, the `select` option prints the user's selection to the developer console, just for reference so you can actually respond to a user's selection.

For a more complete jquery-autocomplete example see the 'Load Data with AJAX' section [here](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html).

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks