# Cannot get autocomplete to work with Jquery and Flask

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, flask

I am trying to query the database and return a list of phone numbers. I've tried a few different methods to no avail.

I followed this example, the solution portion, but it does not work. No errors or nothing, just does not autocomplete or return data from the database. [jQuery autocomplete in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704997/jquery-autocomplete-in-flask).

Flask

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    search = TextField('', id='autocomplete')
   # search = TextField('', [validators.Length(min=2, max=50)])

@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('q')
    c, conn = connection()
    qry = "SELECT Distinct PhoneNumber FROM webappdb.posts where cast(PhoneNumber as Char) LIKE (%s)"
    c.execute(qry,(str(search)+'%',))
    results = c.fetchall()
    return jsonify(matching_results=results)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    form=SearchForm(request.form)
    return render_template("index.html", form = form)
```

HTML

```
<div align="center">
</div>


            <div style="text-align: center;">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
                <form method="POST"  action="/">
                    <dl id="autocomplete" name ="autocomplete" text="text" style="display:inline-block;">{{render_field(form.search) }}</dl>
                    <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="fetchlist(); return false;">Search</button>
                </form> 
            </div>          

{% if data %}
    <div  style="text-align:center;">   
        <table id="list" style="display:none;" class = "table table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Rating</th>
                <th scope="col">Review</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {% for row in data %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for d in row %}
                            <td>{{ d }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>

{% endif %}
</body>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{
                q: request.term, // in flask, "q" will be the argument to look for using request.args
            }, function(data) {
                response(data.matching_results); // matching_results from jsonify
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.value); // not in your question, but might help later
        }
    });
})

function fetchlist() {
    if (document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
    }
    else document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'inline';
}
</script>
```

Comment: If no data is returned from the db, then perhaps you should do some debugging there.

Comment: @Shadow i can print the results from the db, but it does not show up in the autocomplete feature.

Comment: i change the line that renders the search form field to
~~~
<input id="autocomplete" name ="autocomplete" text="text" style="display:inline-block;"></input>
~~~
and now it generates the autocomplete, but no values are in there, but in the query that is returned from the db I can see the data.